# Java Swing elements change every runtime

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, positioning, absolutelayout

So I made a program using java's swing library. I made a program that graphs equations and here is the main method if it's relevant:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    JFrame frame= new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));

    GraphPanel gp = new GraphPanel();
    GraphPanel gp2 = new GraphPanel();

    //gp.functs.add(new Function(Phrase.createPhrase("2(25-x^2)^(1/2)")));
    //gp.functs.add(new Function(Phrase.createPhrase("-1.1((25-x^2)^(1/2))")));
    gp.functs.add(new Function(Phrase.createPhrase("x^2")));
    //gp.functs.add(new Function(Phrase.createPhrase("-4/x^2+6")));
    gp2.functs.add(new Function(Phrase.createPhrase("sinx")));

    frame.add(gp);
    frame.add(gp2);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(800, 800);


    //gp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
    gp.setBounds(100, 100, 700, 700);//I WANT THIS TO ALWAYS RUN

}
```

I ran two trial runs of the program WITHOUT CHANGING ANY PART OF IT and this is what it looked like:

[image]

Then the next time i ran it:

[image: Second run]

If it's relevant, GraphPanel is of type JLabel.
I know that if i use a null absolute LayoutManager, it will always work. But I'm just wondering why swing has such inconsistencies in it. I've noticed stuff like this before but I though it was just some error in the program. Why is this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Start by moving `frame.setVisible(true);` to the end of the `main` method
- This `gp.setBounds(100, 100, 700, 700);` is pointless, as `gp` is under the control of a layout manager (`GridLayout`)
- There's no point in using both `path` and `setSize`, `pack` is generally a safer option, but that will depend on your components correctly overriding `getPreferredSize`

> But I'm just wondering why swing has such inconsistencies in it. I've noticed stuff like this before but I though it was just some error in the program. Why is this?

Mostly because you're not using the API properly.  It's possible, because of the way a `JFrame` is physically attached to a native peer, that the frame may or may not actually be visible on the screen when you reach `gp.setBounds`.

Also, because you're doing all your work from within the "main" thread and not the Event Dispatching Thread, you're running the risk of a race condition between them, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details.

Swing is VERY flexible, it's also unforgiving when you do the wrong things (or things the wrong way)

Comment: But how come it worked one time but not the other? Shouldn't it either always work or never work?

Comment: See update, it's possible you have a race condition between the "main" thread and the Event Dispatching Thread (among other things)

Comment: That makes sense that one time the main method might have reached set bounds before the frame was actually displayed...Alright thanks!